# i cant play my animation after playing it once in play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

i recently made a sword attack animation for my game, the animation it self is perfect but when i enter play mode and play the animation (by left clicking) it only plays once and when i press left click again it doesn't do anything, i want it to trigger the animation whenever i press left click while holding my sword

code:

```
public class animationactivation : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
 public GameObject Sword;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("mouse 0"))
    {
        Sword.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("swing sword");
    }

   
   

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a code where your sword goes back to idle after your sword animation finish playing, like this:

```cs
public class AnimationActivation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Sword;
    public bool CanAttack = true;//this is to ready your sword for another attack
    public float AttackCooldown = 1.0f;//this is how much time your sword will go back to idle again

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("mouse 0"))
        {
            CanAttack = false;
            Sword.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("swing sword");
            StartCoroutine(ResetAttackCooldown())
        }      
    }
    
    // This code activates the cooldown
    IEnumerator ResetAttackCooldown()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AttackCooldown);
        CanAttack = true;
    }

}
```